# Не отображается видео с youtube в phonegap iphone 5s

Tags: видео, phonegap, youtube, cordova

Делаю мобильную версию сайта пока под Android. Результат смотрю через Phonegap dev app на iPhone 5S.

Хочу, чтобы пользователь мог просматривать с приложения видео с Youtube встроенное через iframe, но почему-то не передает изображение видео Phonegap, в браузере локально оно стоит и работает, а вот в Phonegap его нет, когда сделал билд и запустил его на Android, видео и звук есть, чему очень удивился. Подозреваю, что если запустить билд на iPhone 5S результат будет тот же, что и с Phonegap, почему?